# AS3 Scaling an MC with the mouse working... sort of

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to scale a rectangle by clicking and dragging on it. The code below works, **sort of**, but I'm looking for possible improvements in performance and accuracy. The idea is to click, drag and resize, just in the horizontal. One frustrating thing is that it stops scrolling when mouse is DOWN but no longer over the MC.

```
var isPressed:Boolean = false;

mcMXredBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moved);
mcMXredBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressed);
mcMXredBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, released);


function moved(e:Event):void{
if (isPressed) 
this.scaleX = 1 + (mouseX/100);
}

function pressed(e:MouseEvent):void{
isPressed = true;
moved(e);
}
function released(e:MouseEvent):void{
isPressed = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change it to something like the below:

```
mcMXredBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressed);

var initMouseX;

function moved(e:Event):void{
    this.width += (mouseX - initMouseX);
    initMouseX = mouseX;
}

function pressed(e:MouseEvent):void{
    initMouseX = mouseX;

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, released);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moved);

    moved(e);
}

function released(e:MouseEvent):void{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, released);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moved);
}
```

By adding the listeners when the mouse is pressed down (and removing when released), you no longer have to poll to see if the mouse is down so this will save performance when not dragging. Adding to the stage will solve your problem of it not registering when the mouse is no longer over the object. Finally, there are some tweaks to working out the maths of dragging.

Comment: Yep, that works better. The polling thing makes sense and the tweaks for dragging work better too. Is there a reason the MC moves slightly towards the direction of scaling e.g. scaling up pulls it right a bit, too?

Comment: Is the symbol's registration point at the far left edge (x = 0)? If not, then that may cause the object to move when scaling.

Comment: Yep, tried moving it around too but it's not sitting still. I guess it's in the math for dragging or something.

Comment: That one's a bit tricky to work out without seeing the FLA file, there's nothing suss about the Math above, it's just extending the width by the amount the mouse has moved.

Comment: That's the only code in the FLA file, so I'll take another look at the registration point. (I'll use it in another file later but for testing purposes, whilst learning AS3, I start things in a fresh file.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` events to a parent display object or, perhaps, the Stage.

For instance:

```
mcMXredBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressed);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moved);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, released);
```